# MariaDB "freezes" during mariabackup operation

Tags: backup, mariadb, locking

**The Scenario:**

I have a MariaDB running in a server named dbmaster, in a dedicated ProxMox server. This *dbmaster* runs:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- MariaDB 10.3.31 (installed from repository)
- maria-backup 1:10.3.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 (installed from repository)

We want a backup of this MariaDB and restore it in a Windows VPS external to our dedicated server, where MSPowerBI will connect and pull it's data.

**First try:**

We perform a mysqldump every few hours. So we decided to send each of these backups to the Windows VPS via OpenSSH. But for some unknown reason, the restore took more than an hour, and we decided to abort this method.

**Second Try:**

We used mariabackup to create the physical backups, which was pleasantly fast. It was working really fine, but today it just hold MariaDB frozen, and no connection could be done. This is the command we use:

```
mariabackup --backup --target-dir="/mnt/external01/backup/"
```

The user and password for mariabackup is in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/99-company.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
max_connections           = 400               # Limit of open connections. Check with show global max_used_connections

innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 7G     # Go up to 70% of your available RAM
innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = 7      # Bigger if huge InnoDB Buffer Pool or high concurrency

innodb_file_per_table          = 1      # Is the recommended way nowadays
# innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT   # O_DIRECT is sometimes better for direct attached storage
innodb_write_io_threads        = 8      # If you have a strong I/O system or SSD
innodb_read_io_threads         = 8      # If you have a strong I/O system or SSD
innodb_io_capacity             = 1000   # If you have a strong I/O system or SSD

#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2     # 1 for durability, 0 or 2 for performance
#innodb_log_buffer_size         = 8M    # Bigger if innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
#innodb_log_file_size           = 256M  # Bigger means more write throughput but longer recovery time

[mariabackup]
user=UserName
password=UserPassword
```

These are the messages mariabackup produced:

```
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 Connecting to MySQL server host: localhost, user: mariabackup, password: set, port: not set, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 Using server version 10.3.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
mariabackup based on MariaDB server 10.3.31-MariaDB debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 uses posix_fadvise().
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 cd to /var/lib/mysql/
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 open files limit requested 0, set to 1024
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 mariabackup: using the following InnoDB configuration:
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 innodb_data_home_dir = 
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 innodb_log_group_home_dir = ./
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-12-01 16:00:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 mariabackup: Generating a list of tablespaces
2021-12-01 16:00:02 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Allocated tablespace ID 328091 for company/segments, old maximum was 0
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 >> log scanned up to (7032916728189)
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 Copying ibdata1 to /mnt/external01/backup/ibdata1
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:02         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 Copying ./company/segments.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/segments.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:02         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 Copying ./company/recoveries.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/recoveries.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:02         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 Copying ./company/states.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/states.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:02         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 Copying ./company/hub_bill_payments.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/hub_bill_payments.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:02         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 Copying ./company/categories.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/categories.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:02         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 Copying ./company/cron_services.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/cron_services.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:02         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:02 Copying ./company/company_revenues.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/company_revenues.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/user_fcm_tokens.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/user_fcm_tokens.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/lucky_numbers.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/lucky_numbers.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/store_withdraws.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_withdraws.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/loan_account_balances.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/loan_account_balances.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/hub_transfer_banks.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/hub_transfer_banks.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/products.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/products.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/access_profiles.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/access_profiles.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/awards_raffles.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/awards_raffles.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/installments.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/installments.ibd
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 >> log scanned up to (7032916728927)
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/loan_assigments.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/loan_assigments.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/sms_recovery_codes.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/sms_recovery_codes.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/emails.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/emails.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/outgoings.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/outgoings.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/store_account_extracts.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_account_extracts.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/campaigns.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/campaigns.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/orders.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/orders.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/bitpay_notifications.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/bitpay_notifications.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/user_delivery_addresses.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/user_delivery_addresses.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/user_funding_requests.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/user_funding_requests.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/email_users.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/email_users.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/shipments.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/shipments.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:03 Copying ./company/logged_exceptions.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/logged_exceptions.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/rate_range_groups.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/rate_range_groups.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/sustainable_villages.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/sustainable_villages.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/store_payment_requests.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_payment_requests.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/machine_historics.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/machine_historics.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/user_access_profiles.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/user_access_profiles.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/loan_funding_requests.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/loan_funding_requests.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/segment_settings.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/segment_settings.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/loan_applications.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/loan_applications.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/store_withdraw_histories.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_withdraw_histories.ibd
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 >> log scanned up to (7032916729113)
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/company_configurations.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/company_configurations.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/push_notifications.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/push_notifications.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/hub_transfers.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/hub_transfers.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/user_admins.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/user_admins.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/email_registrations.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/email_registrations.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/user_cards.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/user_cards.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/loan_incomes.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/loan_incomes.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/dogs.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/dogs.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/store_agreements.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_agreements.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/store_outgoings.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_outgoings.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/version_controls.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/version_controls.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/reports.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/reports.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/store_split_payments.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_split_payments.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/settlements.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/settlements.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/white_labels.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/white_labels.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/lucky_number_balances.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/lucky_number_balances.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/store_receiver_payments.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_receiver_payments.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/store_brand_setting_requests.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_brand_setting_requests.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/pix_qrcodes.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/pix_qrcodes.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/store_machines.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_machines.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/cashback_payments.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/cashback_payments.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/users.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/users.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/cnab_loans.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/cnab_loans.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/shipment_daily_files.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/shipment_daily_files.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/store_qrcodes.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_qrcodes.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/stores.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/stores.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/cpf_error_validations.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/cpf_error_validations.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/machines.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/machines.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/mobile_chip_providers.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/mobile_chip_providers.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:04 Copying ./company/audits.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/audits.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/campaign_stores.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/campaign_stores.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/machine_app_versions.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/machine_app_versions.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/store_employees.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_employees.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/account_extract_groups.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/account_extract_groups.ibd
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 >> log scanned up to (7032916729122)
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/arbi_notifications.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/arbi_notifications.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/app_banner_product_campaigns.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/app_banner_product_campaigns.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/banks.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/banks.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/permission_groups.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/permission_groups.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/store_ratings.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_ratings.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/push_notification_users.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/push_notification_users.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/offers.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/offers.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/store_item_ratings.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_item_ratings.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/donation_banners.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/donation_banners.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/campaign_week_days.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/campaign_week_days.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/vouchers.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/vouchers.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/store_rate_range_requests.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_rate_range_requests.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/raffles.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/raffles.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/user_credit_cards.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/user_credit_cards.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/hub_cards.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/hub_cards.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/user_block_histories.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/user_block_histories.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/anticipation_requests.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/anticipation_requests.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/machine_stories.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/machine_stories.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/store_receivers.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_receivers.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/one_signal_devices.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/one_signal_devices.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:05 Copying ./company/member_locations.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/member_locations.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/reading_adiq_edis.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/reading_adiq_edis.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/user_stores.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/user_stores.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/store_working_days.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_working_days.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/store_payment_request_items.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_payment_request_items.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/store_setting_requests.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_setting_requests.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/installment_splits.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/installment_splits.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/hub_callbacks.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/hub_callbacks.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/elo_card_informations.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/elo_card_informations.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/loan_account_extracts.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/loan_account_extracts.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/cashbacks.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/cashbacks.ibd
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 >> log scanned up to (7032916729122)
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/schema_migrations.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/schema_migrations.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/arbi_requests.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/arbi_requests.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/default_cashbacks.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/default_cashbacks.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/rate_ranges.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/rate_ranges.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/store_histories.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_histories.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/access_profile_permissions.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/access_profile_permissions.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:06 Copying ./company/account_registers.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/account_registers.ibd
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:07 >> log scanned up to (7032916729122)
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:07         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:07 Copying ./company/user_favorite_stores.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/user_favorite_stores.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:07         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:07 Copying ./company/store_settings.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/store_settings.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:07         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:07 Copying ./company/recharges.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/recharges.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:07         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:07 Copying ./company/business_groups.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company/business_groups.ibd

... Many tables ...

[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:11 Copying ./company_payments/accounts.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company_payments/accounts.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:11         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:11 Copying ./company_payments/orders.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company_payments/orders.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:11         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:11 Copying ./company_payments/users.ibd to 

... Many tables ...

/mnt/external01/backup/company_proxy/receipts.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:11         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:11 Copying ./company_proxy/campaigns.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company_proxy/campaigns.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:11         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:11 Copying ./company_proxy/store_transaction_paystores.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company_proxy/store_transaction_paystores.ibd
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:12 >> log scanned up to (7032916729489)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:13 >> log scanned up to (7032916729489)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:14 >> log scanned up to (7032916729489)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:15 >> log scanned up to (7032916729489)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:16 >> log scanned up to (7032916729489)
2021-12-01 16:00:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Read redo log up to LSN=7032916729856
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:17 >> log scanned up to (7032916729489)
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:17         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:17 Copying ./company_proxy/logged_exceptions.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company_proxy/logged_exceptions.ibd

... Many tables ...

/mnt/external01/backup/company_proxy/store_transactions.ibd
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:19 >> log scanned up to (7032916729489)
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:19         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:19 Copying ./company_proxy/ar_internal_metadata.ibd to /mnt/external01/backup/company_proxy/ar_internal_metadata.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:19         ...done
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:19 Copying ./company_proxy/crono_jobs.ibd to 

... Many tables ...

/mnt/external01/backup/mysql/transaction_registry.ibd
[01] 2021-12-01 16:00:19         ...done
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:20 >> log scanned up to (7032916729489)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:20 Executing FLUSH NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG TABLES...
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:21 >> log scanned up to (7032916729489)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:22 >> log scanned up to (7032916729489)
...
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:30 >> log scanned up to (7032916729489)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:00:31 >> log scanned up to (7032916729489)
...
2021-12-01 16:01:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Read redo log up to LSN=7032916743168
[00] 2021-12-01 16:01:47 >> log scanned up to (7032916742804)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:01:48 >> log scanned up to (7032916742804)
...
[00] 2021-12-01 16:01:59 >> log scanned up to (7032916742804)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:02:00 >> log scanned up to (7032916742804)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:02:01 >> log scanned up to (7032916744013)
2021-12-01 16:02:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Read redo log up to LSN=7032916753920

             ...

      Many similar messages

             ...

[00] 2021-12-01 16:39:24 >> log scanned up to (7032917237239)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:39:25 >> log scanned up to (7032917237239)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:39:31 >> log scanned up to (7032917237239)
2021-12-01 16:39:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Read redo log up to LSN=7032917237248
[00] 2021-12-01 16:39:32 >> log scanned up to (7032917237239)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:39:33 >> log scanned up to (7032917237239)
...
[00] 2021-12-01 16:39:45 >> log scanned up to (7032917237239)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:39:46 >> log scanned up to (7032917237239)
2021-12-01 16:39:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Read redo log up to LSN=7032917237248
[00] 2021-12-01 16:39:47 >> log scanned up to (7032917237239)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:39:48 >> log scanned up to (7032917237239)
...
[00] 2021-12-01 16:40:00 >> log scanned up to (7032917237239)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:40:01 >> log scanned up to (7032917237239)
2021-12-01 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Read redo log up to LSN=7032917241856
[00] 2021-12-01 16:40:02 >> log scanned up to (7032917241583)
[00] 2021-12-01 16:40:05 >> log scanned up to (7032917241699)
[00] FATAL ERROR: 2021-12-01 16:40:06 failed to execute query FLUSH NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG TABLES: Server shutdown in progress
```

On 16:40 we restarted MariaDB and it became responsive again.

**The question:**

What may have happened to cause this huge database lock?

Comment: How much data (gigabytes) in the databases?

Comment: @RickJames, "du -sh" says that MariaDB files uses 7.6Gb of disk.

Comment: "mariabackup to create the physical backups" -- Please elaborate.  Where are those backups?  That is, are they on the machine with mariadb or on the Windows machine?  Is the question about backing up or about restoring?  (Or both?)

Comment: Well, since you are cppying .ibd data files, that implies MyISAM, is there any reason to avoid INNODB managed data (for improved performance?

Comment: What is your result for this query?  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;

Comment: @RickJames, as I mentioned in "The Scenario", the Database is in a Linux server. I want to restore this backup copy from the Linux Server in the Windows Server.

Comment: @RickJames, the question is about the MariaDB freezing during the mariabackup. Note that it happened only once, after many successful executions, but this problem happened during the usage peak, and we don't want to go through this anymore. We are trying to understand if this is a software problem or a misconfiguration.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, we are using the mariabackup software, which is a fork from Percona XtraBackup. And yes, it copies the physical files. But we use InnoDB instead of MyISAM. But you are right, we are focusing in performance, and that's why we are trying mariabackup.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, the result of "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;" is 440.

Comment: @GilbertoMartins - "During peak usage" -- A guess:  The added burden on the system (I/O, CPU, plus locks, etc) led to a cascade of things.  Imagine going into a store that has too many customers in it.  Everyone is slowed down by everyone else.

Comment: Additional information request from Linux server, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Your MariaDB \*.err log would perhaps be more relevant than the backup log. Run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_error';` to find it. (For reference, see [Error log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/error-log/) in the documentation.) AFAICT there is nothing unusual in the backup log until the last line. Just to be clear, did you *cause* that line by restarting MariaDB, or did you restart MariaDB *after* you saw that line?

Comment: I do appreciate your support, but unfortunately this project had to be abandoned, so I couldn't get additional information. Please, can someone guide me? Because I guess this post should be deleted, right? I just want to follow this community's best practices in this case.